# String is getting reduced in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, string

I am using a string to get the base64 string of an image (which I have stored in values/strings.xml). But when I try to copy the contents of that string onto another string, a few characters in the end of the original string do not get copied to the second string. The length of the original string is 4072 characters.

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private Context context;

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Activity activity;

        public Task(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Fetching data");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                originalString = getResources().getString(R.string.s7);
                Log.i("orig", originalString);

                copiedString = originalString;
                Log.i("copy", copiedString);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("excep", "hello");
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            if(result == null){
                 Log.d("TEMP_LOG","content is null");
                 return;
                }

        }

    }
```

Here is the log results of both strings.

```
09-12 19:44:16.382: I/orig(13150): 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

09-12 19:44:16.406: I/copy(13150): 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
```

As you can see, the second string has 3 characters missing in the end. How is that possible?

Comment: did you try to log strings length to check if it's actually cut or it's logcat that is cutting it? and, copiedString = originalString is actually copying it, or it's just copying a reference to the same string object?

Comment: Are originalString and copiedString  both Strings?  You might want to show the declarations.   Also if you edit your post, add a space before the second logcat line so they will line up (i tried to edit this but SO wouldn't let me -- saying hadn't made enough changes)

Comment: Is the fact that this happens in an AsyncTask relevant?  Have you tried the same code in your Activity?

Comment: With the `copiedString = originalString` you actually only copy the reference. Both are pointing to the same memory space, so they're the same (not a copy). Assuming, that both variables are really `String`. I say, we're starring at the wrong piece of code. Something is happening to that String elsewhere in the system - parallel to this AsyncTask/Thread.

Comment: In your code you are not copying the String, it is just `copiedString` variable will also point to the object to which `originalString` variable was pointing. So, cutting of string is not the case. Yes as @Selvin said it might be Logcat's output issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments pretty much answer the question, but here it is as an answer:

1. Copy the actual String as:

   ```
   String copied = new String(original);
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   String copied = original.clone();
   ```

   Though String objects in Java are immutable so I don't think this is the problem (see #2).
2. Do a String.length() check on the original and copies and log that. The problem is actually probably in the logger itself and thus whatever the source problem is likely lies elsewhere.